# How do you retrieve the submodules for a repo?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

For example, I have a repo, and one subfolder is empty because the code from another repo goes there...

What command do I use so the submodule is retrieved and added in all locations of my local repo where submodules are needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git submodule update --init
```

or (when you didn't clone the repository yet)

```
git clone -i /path/to/parentRepo
```

have a look at

```
git submodule --help
```

Comment: Thanks! Why is that so hard to find on Google? Also, is the --init option required? What's the difference without it?

Comment: The difference is, that the submodules are not initialized (as the name suggests ;)). `git submodule update --init` is just a shortcut for `git submodule init && git submodule update`. `init` write the required informations for the submodules from the versioned `.gitmodule` into the repositories `.git/config`